# How to include file in code (not in header) c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream  
#include <string  
#include <fstream>  
using namespace std;

int main() {  
    string file = "mycode.h";  
    #include file  
}
```

I want to include some code from another file but to user can type location of file than code to be used

Comment: #include instructions are executed at compile time so this will not work

Comment: is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @H2102M It depends what is in `mycode.th`.  Is it just data, or is it actual code?

Comment: @0x5453 it is code

Comment: For interactive #include of code an interpreter is needed. See the links in the other answer below about the Cling C++ interpreter.

Comment: Are you really sure this is what you want to do?

Comment: Your `#include` instructions at the top miss the closing `>`.

Comment: If you want to interpret code at runtime, I would recommend that code to be something else than `c++`. Choosing another language will give you many more options for interpreters that can be embedded into your program.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.

C++ has to be compiled to convert the source code into executable code. `#include` is a preprocessor command, which is executed at an early compilation stage to combine different source files into a single file that is further processed by the compiler.

The final executable file contains so-called machine-code that is specific for a CPU and an operating system, but in general it does not contain the source code (except maybe for debugging purposes).

Maybe you can solve your problem by an external control program that the user runs and that receives the include path as input, inserts it into the source code, calls the compiler, and executes the compiled executable.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic include in C++ I think you may need a C++ interpreter. There's one, called Cling:

https://root.cern/cling/

https://github.com/root-project/cling

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for JIT compilation; I think CLing can work for you: https://github.com/root-project/cling

if you check the documents you will see it is doing what you are asking,

ref: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29344/jit-compiler-for-c-c-and-the-likes